# ViewDidLoad not called from didSelectRowAtIndexPath splitviewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uisplitviewcontroller

I am trying to load a single (storyboard id:ClaimReportView) ViewControllers with diff data depending upon the  rows clicked on the table view of MasterVC. But the viewDidload is called only once for the VC and hence if i trying to click on diff rows in table view it doesn't call the viewdidload.

.M file

```
@interface LAMasterViewController ()
{
    NSArray *_claimReports;

}
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    LAClaimReport *record = [_claimReports objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    if ([record.submitted isEqualToNumber:@0]  )
    {
        UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
        self.claimReportViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ClaimReportView"];
        [self.detailViewController.navigationController setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObject:self.claimReportViewController] animated:YES];

        self.claimReportViewController.claimReport = record;
    }

}
```

.h file

```
@interface LAMasterViewController : UITableViewController
@property (strong, nonatomic) LADetailViewController *detailViewController;
@property (strong,nonatomic) LAClaimReportViewController *claimReportViewController;
```

@end

What am i missing here? i think i haven't pushed the VC in navigation Stack so ViewDidLoad not called? pls guide.

Comment: I think you can reload UITableView instead of trying to launch the same ViewController again.

Comment: How do you know that `viewDidLoad` is not called?  Have you placed a breakpoint there and confirmed it, or is it simply that the `claimReport` property is nil?  If the latter then it could be a race condition - `viewDidLoad` is being called before the `self.claimReportViewController.claimReport = record;`

Comment: i kept a breakpoint there Paulw11

Comment: The documentation for `instantiateViewController` says that it always returns a new instance, so `viewDidLoad` should run, however you may have better luck with your code in `viewWillAppear` or `viewDidAppear`.  Alternatively create a custom setter for the `claimReport` property - this is probably the most 'correct' solution as it will ensure that the view details are refreshed whenever the underlying data model changes

Answer (score 2):

`viewDidLoad` is called once when your view is loaded in the first time so there will be no affect in `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method . Its better you can create your own method and call that method in the `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method that will work for you.

Comment: you mean a method that will call viewdidload method. and call that method from didSelectRowAtIndexPath.

Comment: no , you wirte some code in viewdidload which supposed to work in didSelectRowAtIndexPath method but unfortunate it will not work. SO cut those code and create your own method and paste those code in that method. You can call ur method in didSelectRowAtIndexPath method  that it

Comment: the code in viewDidload belongs to diff. class. Putting that under the didselectRowAtIndexPath in other class will break the concept of OOP.

Answer (score 0):

You can not call `viewDidLoad` method because it is `viewController`'s life cycle method that can not be called manually, it will be called automatically when view is loaded.